# SQL Server : Query optimization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

Does SQL Server or SQL Server Compact Edition have built-in optimization for queries like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT *
        FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM table) ) )
```

I have nice looking recursive function and I don't want to change code

```
    const string QUERY_SELECT = @"SELECT
                                      *
                                  FROM ( {0} ) AS RESULT
                                  WHERE
                                      {1} IN
                                      (
                                          SELECT
                                              {1}
                                          FROM ( {0} ) AS RESULT
                                          GROUP BY
                                              {1}
                                          HAVING
                                              COUNT( * ) > 1
                                      )";

    private string buildSelect( string[] fields )
    {
        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM [file]"; // ISSUE 1

        foreach ( string field in fields )
        {
            this.buildSelect( ref commandText, field );
        }

        return commandText;
    }

    private void buildSelect( ref string commandText, string field )
    {
        commandText = String.Format
        (
            QUERY_SELECT,
            commandText,
            field
        );
    }

    this.buildSelect( new string[] { "length", "extension" } );
```

The problem is brackets "()" :

```
 ( [file] ) AS RESULT    ----> error
```

But I need brackets for

```
SELECT * FROM SELECT
```

Comment: What is your recursive code like ?

Comment: well that code would not work in sql server at all as it would not pass a syntax check. Derived tables need aliases.

Comment: @HLGEM please look again

Comment: If possible, use an ORM which will handle it for you, and get busy with what matters most, the business concerns.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller, that is a ridiculous comment.  Data is far more important to the business than application code and ORMs are less than useful for many types of queries.

Comment: @HLGEM: I agree that data is far more important, since if there was no information to handle, there wouldn't be any need for any information systems. Aside, I have never come across any situation where an ORM such as NHibernate cannot handle adequately, particularly because it does handle stored procedures for more complex cases. Besides, if a recursive query is really required, this looks to me like something that smells either in the data architecture, or the design of the whole application.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I think that's the real meat of it there isn't it. That stored procedures need to be called for more complex cases when the ORM makes inefficient queries. I.e. if you have a complex query, don't use an ORM for it. Recursive queries are perfectly valid and natural data structures. (this query happens to be a sub-query and not recursive but still)

Comment: I need to find duplicates by several fields

Comment: @Brad: I disagree, since 98% (arbitrary percentage) of the applications don't require complex queries to be performed against the underlying data store. Using an ORM along with stored procedure requires you to only map your stored procedure to your repository and you're done. The ORM then keeps a level of abstraction from the rest of the application.

Comment: @Madyuskin: Might you please provide gross example of your data structure and some sample data to help the others figure out what you're trying to achieve?